# Cocoapods Dependencies in Dynamic Framework Module

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoapods

I have an app that has three targets:

- App Target
- Shared Dynamic Framework
- Keyboard Extension

The Xcode project specifies Shared as a target dependency in App and Keyboard (the library has code that is required by both).

My Podfile has a "target" block for each target where I define dependencies. Now, my assumption used to be that any libraries included in "Shared" as Cocoapods dependencies would by virtue of doing so also be available to the App and Keyboard Xcode targets. This however does not seem to be the case at this point. If I instead try to import the a given dependency in all 3 targets, I get duplicate symbols.

Can someone explain to me the proper way to achieve what I'm looking for?

Comment: you have to configure the xcode workspace and then open only the workspace file and NOT the projectfile. did you check the cocoapod documentation? -> https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/the-podfile.html

Comment: I'm definitely using the workspace. I've been a happy cocoa pods user for 3 years, this is specifically an issue with shared dynamic modules.